# error Recaptcha Verifier is only supported in a browser HTTP/HTTPS environment on iOS

Tags: ios, typescript, cordova, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I am brahim i am newbie in ionic tech took my first project for 4 months and i have big problem with authentication with phone number in ios, and customer cares about this problem, please help me, Thank you very much.

I am using this code

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(this.str, appVerifier)
 .then(result => {
   //this.afficher=2;
     this.windowRef.confirmationResult = result;
     localStorage.setItem('email',this.str);
     //this.presentLoadingWithOptions();
 })
 .catch( error => console.log(error) ); }
```

the code works fine in the android, but i have this error in the ios:

> Recaptcha Verifier is only supported in a browser HTTP/HTTPS environment